# How to navigate from carousel slide?

Tags: react-native, navigation, carousel

I just started to learn React Native and don't understand how to make possible navigation from carousel slides. I have a carousel with 4 slides in it and I want to make it possible for a user to go to specific pages after pressing on each of these slides. For every slide, there is a different page.

I tried `const navigation = useNavigation();` method, but it did not work, because a slide is not a function.

I have routes in my App.js:

```
export default function App () {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home"
      screenOptions={{contentStyle:{backgroundColor:'#FFFFFF'}, headerTitle: (props) => <LogoTitle {...props} />, headerRight: (props) => <RightTitle {...props} /> }}>        
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="ItemsCategories" component={ItemsCategories} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Feature1" component={Feature1} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Feature2" component={Feature2} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Here is my code of the Carousel so far:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { Text, View, SafeAreaView, Image, ImageBackground, StyleSheet, Pressable, navigation } from 'react-native';
import Carousel from 'react-native-snap-carousel';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

const horizontalMargin = 20;
const slideWidth = 280;
const slideHeight=470

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  image: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center"
  },
  text: {
    color: "white",
    fontSize: 42,
    lineHeight: 84,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    textAlign: "center",
    textShadowColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75)',
    textShadowOffset: {width: -1, height: 1},
    textShadowRadius: 10,
    width: 350
    
  },
  safe: {
    position: 'absolute',
    left:     0,
    top:      0,
    height: 360 , 
    paddingTop: 10, 
    paddingBottom: 1
  }
});

export default class HomeCarousel extends Component {
  
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          activeIndex:0,
          carouselItems: [
          {
              navigate: "Feature1",
              image: require('./assets/feature1.png'),
              title:"Feature1",
              
          },
          {   
              navigate: "Feature2",
              image: require('./assets/feature2.png'),
              title:"Feature2",
              
          },
          {   
              navigate: "Feature3",
              image: require('./assets/feature3.png'),
              title:"Feature3",
              
          },
          {     
              navigate: "Feature 4",
              image: require('./assets/feature4.png'),
              title:"Feature 4",
              
          },

        ]
      }
    }
    
    _renderItem({item,index}){
        
        return (
          <Pressable onPress={()=>navigation.navigate(item.navigate)}>
          <View style={{
              backgroundColor:'floralwhite',
              borderRadius: 5,
              height: 360,
              padding: 0,
              marginLeft: 0,
              marginRight: 0, }}>
            <ImageBackground source={item.image} resizeMode="cover" style={styles.image}>
            <Text style={styles.text}>{item.title}</Text>
            </ImageBackground>
          </View>
          </Pressable>

        )
    }

    render() {
        return (
          
          <SafeAreaView style={styles.safe}>
            <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection:'row', justifyContent: "center" }}>
                <Carousel
                  layout={"default"}
                  ref={ref => this.carousel = ref}
                  data={this.state.carouselItems}
                  sliderWidth={400}
                  itemWidth={400}
                  renderItem={this._renderItem}
                  onSnapToItem = { index => this.setState({activeIndex:index}) } />
            </View>
          </SafeAreaView>
          
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: You cant use hooks in class components look at the react documentation. `useNavigation` is a hook and can't be used in your `HomeCarousel` class

Comment: I recommend just using function components if you started learning react-native because you will run into less issues like this.

Answer (score 0):

If you just make `HomeCarousel` a functional component then you can do this below and it will work.

```js
export default function  HomeCarousel() {
  
    const [activeIndex,setActiveIndex] = React.useState(0); // search useState online
    const [carouselItems,setCarouselItems] = React.useState( [
          {
              navigate: "Feature1",
              image: require('./assets/feature1.png'),
              title:"Feature1",
              
          },
          {   
              navigate: "Feature2",
              image: require('./assets/feature2.png'),
              title:"Feature2",
              
          },
          {   
              navigate: "Feature3",
              image: require('./assets/feature3.png'),
              title:"Feature3",
              
          },
          {     
              navigate: "Feature 4",
              image: require('./assets/feature4.png'),
              title:"Feature 4",
              
          },

        ]);

    const ref = React.useRef(null); // search useRef online

    
    const Item =({item,index})=> {
        const navigation = useNavigation(); // Now you can use it
        return (
          <Pressable onPress={()=>navigation.navigate(item.navigate)}>
          <View style={{
              backgroundColor:'floralwhite',
              borderRadius: 5,
              height: 360,
              padding: 0,
              marginLeft: 0,
              marginRight: 0, }}>
            <ImageBackground source={item.image} resizeMode="cover" style={styles.image}>
            <Text style={styles.text}>{item.title}</Text>
            </ImageBackground>
          </View>
          </Pressable>

        )
    }


    return (
      
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.safe}>
        <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection:'row', justifyContent: "center" }}>
            <Carousel
              layout={"default"}
              ref={ref}
              data={carouselItems}
              sliderWidth={400}
              itemWidth={400}
              renderItem={Item}
              onSnapToItem = { index =>setActiveIndex(index) } />
        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
      
    );
  
}
```